# Python: Convert Table with Missing Data and Irregular Pattern to Dictionary

Tags: python, ascii, python-2.6

In Python 2.6, what would be a pythonic way to filter an ASCII table with columns of irregular width, missing data and indented child entries to convert them into a dictionary?

```
col1      col2  col3       col4 
A         B                D          
 A1       B1    C1          
 A2       B2
```

Where you would want an output similar to:

```
{"col1":"A","col2":"B","col3":"","col4":"D",
indented_entries:[
  {"col1":"A1","col2":"B1","col3":"C1","col4":""},
  {"col1":"A2","col2":"B2","col3":"","col4":""}
]}
```

Whilst you can iterate through the fixed character width columns, my question is to as if anyone has an elegant idea of implementation?

---

**Real life scenario**

I have an ASCII Table with some columns and some irregular patterns (indent rows). The data is as below:

```
ty      eq  status       use state  ord   capacity      free    ra  part high low
ma      10  m----3---r-   1% on          558.912G  555.888G    1M    16   80% 70%
 mm      11               1% on       0  558.912G  558.894G  [586042464 inodes]
 mr      12               1% on       1  558.912G  555.888G
```

I would like to parse this data into a dictionary so it would look like this:

```
{
  "ty": "ma",
  "eq": "10",
  "status": "m----3---r-",
  "use": "1%",
  "state": "on",
  "capacity": "558.912G",
  "free": "555.888G",
  "ra": "1M",
  "part": "16",
  "high": "80%",
  "low": "70%",
  "_ty": [
    {
      "ty": "mm",
      "eq": "11",
      "use": "1%",
      "state": "on",
      "ord": "0",
      "capacity": "558.912G",
      "free": "558.894G [586042464 inodes]"
    },
    {
      "ty": "m4",
      "eq": "12",
      "use": "1%",
      "state": "on",
      "ord": "1",
      "capacity": "558.912G",
      "free": "555.888G"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to know an elegant way to do this in Python (2.6). Any thoughts?

A solution that disregards the "child lines" and returns only the top level would also be considered.

Some of my attempts:

```
def panda_conversion(filename):
        import pandas
        return pandas.read_csv(filename,sep='\s+').T.to_dict()


def convert_table_to_dict(filename):
        import csv
        return list(csv.DictReader(open(filename), delimiter=' '))


def convert_ascii_table(filename):
        import asciitable
        return asciitable.read(filename, Reader=asciitable.FixedWidth,
                col_starts=( 0, 8,  12, 25, 29, 37, 41, 51, 61, 69, 73, 78 ),
                col_ends  =( 2, 11, 23, 28, 34, 40, 50, 60, 68, 71, 76, 81 ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        import json
        filename = sys.argv[1:][0]
        print( panda_conversion( filename ) )
        print( json.dumps( convert_table_to_dict( filename ), indent=1))
        print( convert_ascii_table( filename ) )
```

By the way, as according to the comments I was not doing this properly, you do not need to post code. Just thoughts are enough. Thanks.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Figure out how to parse the different types of lines; write parsing function(s); iterate over every line and decide which function to parse it with; after parsing, add it, as appropriate, to your container(s).

Comment: Thanks, @Prune. The haven’t found where my question is non-compliant. I don’t do StackOverflow very often so apologies for being awkward. I know how to do it, I could iterate for a each line and parse it, determining the breadth of each column (start and end) character. I just assumed this was a bad approach and would like to discuss with other who might have faced a similar issue in the past.

Comment: @gtamorim: you've made no attempt to solve the problem on your own.  The problem as a whole is outside the scope of SO.

Comment: I made it. Just not happy with it. The last one was using asciitable (now discontinued but astropy has replaced it).

Comment: @Prune, could you please reconsider my question. I have taken all the comments into consideration and re-phrased it.

Comment: Yes, it's greatly improved.  I removed my down-vote and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it is very un-pythonic.

```
def iterate(filename):
        d={}
        f = open(filename,'r')
        header = f.readline().split()
        header_parent = list(header)
        header_parent.remove("ord")
        header_child = [e for e in header if e not in ("status","part","high","low" )]

        for line in f:
                if not line[0] == ' ':
                        for columns in header_parent:
                                d[columns] = line.split()[header_parent.index(columns)]
                else:
                        for columns in header_child:
                                d["_"+columns] = '' if (header_child.index(columns) >= len(line.split()) ) else line.split()[header_child.index(columns)]

        return d
```

Do you see how this could be improved?

Comment: That answer (together with an edited version of your question) would be a good fit for codereview.se

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. I will do that.